# How can I add an object into an array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a array in a app.js file like this:

```
   var data = [
                {id:1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith'},
                {id:2, firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Smith'},
                {id:3, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'}
              ];
```

Right now, I am using Node.js and trying to create a function call addEmployee() in a module.js file. addEmplyee() only takes two argurments, the firstName and lastName of being added. The id value should be calculated as one more than the current maximum id using underscore.js.
Here is my code in module.js file, however it doesn't work.

```
var _ = require('underscore');
module.exports = {
    addEmployee: function (firstName, lastName) {

        function Person(id, firstName, lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.id = function (data) {
                var id = _.max(data, function (data) {
                    return data.id;
                });
                return id.id + 1;
            }
            var person = new Person(id, firstName, lastName);
            data.push(person);
            return data;

        }
    }
}
```

Is any one can help? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @lupatus : Not recursive exactly, I used the wrong wording. But when op creates an object for person again, then when function is called again it will create object, correct right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
module.exports = {
    addEmployee: function (firstName, lastName) {

        function Person(id, firstName, lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.id = (function (data) {
                var id = _.max(data, function (data) {
                    return data.id;
                });
                return id.id + 1;
            })();    //IIFE to invoke function immidiately and thus assign value to id
            data.push({id: this.id,firstName: this.firstName,lastName: this.lastName});
            return data;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @A.J Thank you so much! However, I got undefined. Maybe, I didn't explain very well. my data variable is in another js file called app.js. Should I import this data to module.js first? If yes, how can I do that in node.js? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
// import data

module.exports = {
    addEmployee: function (firstName, lastName) {
        // remove id
        function Person(firstName, lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.id = (function (data) {
                var id = _.max(data, function (data) {
                    return data.id;
                });
                return id.id + 1;
            })();    
        }

        // put OUTSIDE - dont need id here
        var person = new Person(firstName, lastName);
        data.push(person);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Daniel Tran, Thank you so much! However, I got an error:      var person = new Person(id, firstName, lastName);
                                ^                                                            ReferenceError: id is not defined          Maybe, I didn't explain very well. my data variable is in another js file called app.js. Should I import this data to module.js first? If yes, how can I do that in node.js? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you do not call this inner function/contstructor in anyway, thus it's not added to array. Secondly do not define `Person` inside a function (it'll be defined as new thing on every call - every new `Person` would be new type). Third thing is that if you'd call your code it'd cause infinite loop (as of calling new on self in constructor will do the same in next new instance and so on). Additionally where do you define/import data?

```
var _ = require('underscore');

// probably it'd be even better to move this to separate module
function Person(id, firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.id = id;
};

module.exports = {
    addEmployee: function (firstName, lastName) {
        data.push(new Person((_.max(data, function (data) {
            return data.id;
        }) + 1), firstName, lastName));
    }
}
```

I'd also recommend `lodash` instead of `undescore` (drop-in replacement, but better written).

---

If you need only object keeping the data `{ id, firstName, lastName }` you don't need new type `Person`:

```
module.exports = {
    addEmployee: function (firstName, lastName) {
        var id = (_.max(data, function (data) {
            return data.id;
        }) + 1);
        data.push({ id: id, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName });
    }
}
```

If you use node 6.X or 4.X+ (not sure if es6 notation works with all 4.X, for sure 4.4+ will do it) with `'use strict';` it could be even shorter:

```
'use strict';

var _ = require('underscore');

module.exports = {
    addEmployee: function (firstName, lastName) {
        var id = (_.max(data, function (data) {
            return data.id;
        }) + 1);
        data.push({ id, firstName, lastName });
    }
}
```

And at last, I'd recommend to not mutate data (side effects are bad mostly ) - I'd transform this to something like that (assuming node that can do es6):

```
'use strict';

const _ = require('underscore');

module.exports = {
    // note that data comes as input
    addEmployee: function (data, firstName, lastName) {
        // obtain next id
        const id = (_.max(data, function (data) {
            return data.id;
        }) + 1);
        // return new data (old data + new object, but without mutation of initial object)
        return [...data, { id, firstName, lastName }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Iupatus, Thank you so so much for your comprehensive explanation! Sorry, I am new to node.js, so some parts I am still confused. I am still trying to understand your answer, will give you feedback soon.